# VegaLite - Customize label axis according to values

Tags: plot, label, axis, vega-lite

I'm trying to plot a dendrogram using VegaLite. The plot is almost complete, but there is just one thing mixing, which are the axis labels corresponding to the point id. In the figure I plotted, the axis is ordered from 1 to 40. I have a dictionary with the corresponding labels, e.g. if value is 1 then the label is "point10", if value is 30 then label is "point5" and so on. Hence, what I'd like to do is to replace the numbers for the label.

Is it possible to do this in VegaLite? I haven't found a way by reading the Docs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just provide the field of your `pointLabels` in x-axis and then provide sort with field of `value`, with this you will be able to see the pointLabels as labels and the ordering will be displayed as per your values. Refer the below example of sorting on a `Name` field or check the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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).

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Drag a rectangular brush to show (first 20) selected points in a table.",
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "transform": [
    {"window": [{"op": "row_number", "as": "row_number"}]},
    {"calculate": "'My'+datum.Name", "as": "alias"}
  ],
  "params": [{"name": "brush", "select": "interval"}],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Name",
      "type": "nominal",
      "stack": false,
      "sort": {"field": "row_number", "order": "ascending"}
    },
    "y": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "stack": false, "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "condition": {"param": "brush", "field": "Cylinders", "type": "ordinal"},
      "value": "grey"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought about it, but it's not trivial, because the dendrogram uses euclidean distances to be constructed, and once I use "ordinal" or "nominal" for the encoding, I'd lose the correct distancing of the elements.

Comment: oh understood, I don't have any other approach for this.

Comment: I figured a way. I'll post it. Not a nice solution, but it does solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I was not able to solve this by modifying the axis. Although, I did manage a solution. It's not the "correct" way, since what I do is to actually erase the axis, and add a "text" marker with the the labels, and I place it where the axis was.

If anyone is interested, here is a gist with the implementation: https://gist.github.com/davibarreira/74c4274333ac51bbeed627deeb631195